# How to scroll a simple UIView (not uitableview) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added some uitextview in my uiviewcontroller.But some of the textViews are not seen as view is small compared to the number of textViews. So I want scroll it, so that i can see the other textViews also. One more thing-- when i want to type something in the lower textView then it hides because of the iphone keyboard.If somebody knows about it, please give me with  the solution.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use UIScrollView to add UITextView and to scroll textview when keyboard is visible you can use keyboard shown notification.Google it you will find out.

Answer (score 1):

Add UIScrollView in self.view. Now add all subviews to UIScrollView.

Provide contentSize of UIScrollView in width and height.

```
if heigth > 460 it will scroll vertically

if weight > 320 it will scroll horizontally
```

If any condition doesnot matches then u will not be able to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use UIScrollView.Instead of adding all of your subviews(in your case multiple UITextViews) in the main view, just add a srollView in your view and then add all subviews in that scrollView.UIView doesn't have the property to scroll.And don't forget to change the contentSize property of scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a UIScrollView. This is a fundamental class when it comes to iPhone development (and just Apple development in general) and it should be mastered before you continue onto more advanced topics. Here is the documentation for the class :
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html